# PL SQL "Array Type" To TSQL translation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, plsql

This is my initial PL/SQL code :

```
    TYPE VarcharArray IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

and i use it in the following code :

```
 PROCEDURE Create(inFatherId IN VARCHAR2, inBarcode IN VarcharArray, inItemId IN VarcharArray)
 IS
    myCount NUMBER(38);
    sampleId_FromDb NUMBER(38);
    itemId_FromDb NUMBER(38);
 BEGIN
    myCount := inBarcode.COUNT;
    FOR i IN 1..myCount
    LOOP
        SELECT ITEM.Id INTO itemId_FromDb FROM ITEM WHERE FatherId = inFatherId AND CampaignItemId = inItemId(i);
        SELECT SAMPLE_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL INTO sampleId_FromDb FROM DUAL;
        INSERT INTO CAMPAIGN_SAMPLES(Id, Barcode, ItemId) VALUES(sampleId_FromDb, inBarcode(i), itemId_FromDb);
    END LOOP;
 END;
```

I've seen that the array type can be translated into MS SQL with Table-Valued Parameters, however how can i iterate in a similar fashion so that i include in the iteration the thee operations ?

In the current PL/SQL implementation i send up to 50.000 elements in the array and the performance is decent. I would desire something similar also in MS SQL.

Comment: Cursors is the closest you have to iterate, but really, you want to stay away from them. Use set-based programming where possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to be looping and inserting one row at a time. That's just a way to make your code slower. Since tables don't have any order in them, you need to add one column to define the order. Your type would be like this:

```
CREATE TYPE VarcharArray AS TABLE(ID int, Item VARCHAR(100));
```

Then, you can rewrite your procedure as a single INSERT statement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SomeProcedure(
    @FatherId AS VARCHAR, --This might need a length or will be defaulted to length 1
    @Barcode  AS VarcharArray READONLY, 
    @ItemId   AS VarcharArray READONLY
)
AS
    INSERT INTO CAMPAIGN_SAMPLES(Id, Barcode, ItemId) 
    SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR SAMPLE_SEQUENCE,
        bc.Item,
        i.Id 
    FROM ITEM i
    JOIN @ItemId ii ON i.CampaignItemId = ii.Item
    JOIN @Barcode bc ON ii.ID = bc.ID
    WHERE i.FatherId = @FatherId;
```

You could also create a table with both values and prevent any ordering problems that could occur.

```
CREATE TYPE BarcodeItems AS TABLE(Item VARCHAR(100), Barcode VARCHAR(100));

GO
CREATE PROCEDURE SomeProcedure(
    @FatherId AS VARCHAR, --This might need a length or will be defaulted to length 1
    @BarcodeItems  AS BarcodeItems READONLY
)
AS
    INSERT INTO CAMPAIGN_SAMPLES(Id, Barcode, ItemId) 
    SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR SAMPLE_SEQUENCE,
        bi.Item,
        i.Id 
    FROM ITEM i
    JOIN @BarcodeItems bi ON i.CampaignItemId = bi.Item
    WHERE i.FatherId = @FatherId;
```